# How to refer slot element from its slotted element in lit-element?

Tags: polymer, web-component, lit-element, lit-html

I have a component named 'stack-item' which have a slot , its html will look like this

```
<div>
<div>1<div>
<div class='slot-style'><slot></slot></div>
</div>
```

I have used this component like this

```
<stack-item>
   <another-component></another-component>
</stack-item>
```

From 'another-component' how do i get the element reference for class ='slot-style' for calculating the slot width and other properties ?

I wrote a workaround

```
let slotElement =this.shadowRoot.host.parentElement.shadowRoot.querySelector('slot').parentElement;
```

but is there a clean way of achieving this?

Comment: with above line, can you reach the element?

Comment: yes im able to reach @HakanC

Comment: I tested but no way, I could not :(  https://stackblitz.com/edit/litelement-testt-qy3y3c?file=another-component.js

Comment: @HakanC you need to bind the handle change with the context this.handleChange.bind(this) . i liked the event based approach to get the slot. will try it out.

Comment: You are right :)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this can be considered dramatically simpler, but the scenario you give indicates that you already know the host component is stack-item and that component has a slot wrapper with the class name 'slot-style'. Given that you can obtain a reference like this (this works from within the component as well as the host document):

```
let slotElement = document.querySelector("stack-item").shadowRoot.querySelector(".slot-style");
//display width
console.log(slotElement.clientWidth);
```

Answer (score 0):

`this.shadowRoot.host` is equivalent to `this`.

So you could try:

```
this.parentElement.shadowRoot.querySelector( 'div.slot-style' )
```

Comment: Thanks @Supersharp, some times this component ('another-compoent') will be called out side of stack-item.  i was searching for a common solution.

Comment: what i did now is added this code in 'firstUpdated' lifecycle hook of litelement
this.clientWidth = this.getBoundingClientRect().width; 
So that this will trigger the render function again with the actual width.